# Two users working on the same aggregate root in NEventStore

Tags: cqrs, neventstore

I know commands should not fail so I need to validate my command before they are sent.

However, if two users are updating the same aggregate root and both appear to be valid then we would have a concurrency issue.

How do I handle this in NEventStore? Does my clients need to get a version number or commit id that they pass in on saving an event and if it has changed, then I raise an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you alluded to, one way to manage things is to specify the version you're expecting to act on when you `Load` the aggregate (there's an overload for that).

The commit phase will then [via the Domain] yield a `ConcurrencyException` if your generated events clash with ones:-

- already present [that you didn't load into your aggregate].
- written concurrently by competing processes

Make sure you do >1 read of the .doc file that the NuGet package puts into your project - it covers the fundamentals of how the JO EventStore approaches the handling of this.

**UPDATE for clarity** NB While this all works and is sometimes necessary, in general you'll find [and as a default should be working hard to arrive in the happy place where] you can manage most of these conflict resolution things by making your Commands naturally idempotent in nature and/or using natural conflict resolution mechanisms in your system as a whole in order to not need to lean on your Event Store to provide such a low level guard (e.g. etags, retrying Commands in the event of a conflict etc.). If you find yourself going down this path to any major degree in practice, I'd recommend discussing your strategy with sufficient real-world use cases on the DDD-CQRS list.

Comment: I am currently maintaining code and I see _store.OpenStream(aggregateId, 0, int.MaxVersion) when the aggregate is loaded, there are no snapshots in our system. Not clear what this is doing.

Comment: @JD. The `int.MaxVersion` bit means 'load whatever you can find and we'll work from there'. If your edit is based on a specific version, then that would obviously leave you open to retrieving and playing Events subsequent to those which were in force when the editing process began. If you feed in the correct Version number to constrain things, the database PK will do the rest.

Comment: How does the client know what version to pass into _store.OpenStream()? Do I have to persist this somewhere - ie. in my read model?

Comment: @JD. One way is to have the Projection side of the house be told the Version associated with each Event [message]. Then anything that GETs a representation gets the version embedded in the representation and any editing commands can propagate that through as far as the Load(). (Remember that in practice this sort of optimistic concurrency control may or may not be warranted in every case). One thing to be aware of is that [in the case of bugs in your impl etc.] there is no such thing as version 0 (which is a magic value) [so you can make that a validation rule for edited representations]

Comment: Thank you Ruben for all your help.

Comment: @JD. You're welcome (and hat-tip to @ randompunter for prodding to have the answer include recommendations on best practice, i.e., the fact that idempotency is the best way to handle the problem, even if there are low-level mechanisms that can manage the problem)